# loadTest scripting in SoapUI: Inserting Base64-Encoded files into SOAP requests

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, soapui

I am attempting to construct a loadTest in SoapUI wherein a file is selected at random from a pre-determined location on disk and inserted into a SOAP request parameter Base64 encoded; that request is then processed repeatedly according to the parameters of the loadTest. All the files are uniformly named, save for a numeric identifier I can obtain using a random() function.

So far I've set my file location and a random number generator to pull the appropriate files. I'm lukewarm on the concept of message Properties and contexts, but I'm struggling to pull together a coherent strategy for running this kind of test.

Does anyone have any experience with this kind of approach and if so, can any guidance be provided?

I am opting for JavaScript since it is a language I feel more comfortable in, but the documentation around JS in SoapUI specifically as it pertains to loadTesting is a little scattershot, so I'm also looking for help on how to fill gaps in documentation I've been able to chase down.

Thanks!